# What are the conditions that an asymmetric top will perform precession in space (zero torque)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, torque, precession

The conditions that an asymmetric top will perform precession under gravitational field are described in the article [Precession of an Unsymmetrical Top](https://www.nature.com/articles/162365c0).

(I can't get the full article.)

But what if there is no gravitational field or any torque?

Comment: look here http://www.physics.indiana.edu/~dermisek/CM_14/CM-11-4p.pdf

Comment: body with an axis of symmetry has regular precession, but as written in the attached paper, also asymmetric bodies like a triaxial ellipsoid can have precession under some condition, I need to find these conditions, Its hard as I can't get this paper.

Comment: your link describes the precession of axisymmetric bodies

Comment: All the mechanics texts that I am familiar with devote a chapter to this problem. Finding resources on-line for such standard material can be surprisingly difficult, but it might help to search on "tennis racket theorem" or "intermediate axis theorem" (different names for the same thing). We also have some questions on the site covering that topics.

Comment: Does the movement of the asymmetric top, where the axis of rotation is near its long and short axis is the same as precession? like precession is for bodies like a frisbee?